# Bind Image to Image Control

Tags: c#, image

I want to convert the image in the byte[] array and again convert the byte[] array into image and bind that image with the image control. Please check the below code:

```
 private void ShowImage()
        {

            var img = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Section-13.png");
            byte[] image = imageToByteArray(img);
            Image image1 = byteArrayToImage(image);
            Image2.ImageUrl = image1.ToString();
        }

        public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            return ms.ToArray();
        }

        public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
        {

            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
            Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
            return returnImage;
        }
```

Image Control:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" />
```

As you can see in my above code I am passing my image in Image2.ImageUrl by converted it into string. I know I am doing wrong. Please suggest if I am on the right track.

I goggle and find to bind the images in the GridView, but the above code is just for my knowledge my objective is just simply get the image. Thanks in advance.

Comment: image1.ToString() is to convert the image to string data, not the storage url, so I think you should first store the image to a server path, then Image2.ImageUrl = imagepath.

Comment: You mean to say that I first store the image in any temp location on my local and then pass that URL to the image control. Right?

Comment: yes, I think this is the easiest way, although other's said may be helpful, but I think too complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to simply copy this `Section-13.png` inside the folder structure of your web application and then point the `ImageUrl` property to it:

```
Image2.ImageUrl = "~/images/Section-13.png";
```

If on the other hand you want to reference the image from some location outside of your web application then you have 2 possibilities:

1. Write a generic handler which will stream the image to the response and then point the ImageUrl property to this generic handler:

   ```
   public class MyImageHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
       public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
       {
           context.Response.ContentType = "image/png";

           context.Response.WriteFile(@"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Section-13.png");
       }

       public bool IsReusable
       {
           get { return true; }
       }
   }
   ```

   and then:

   ```
   Image2.ImageUrl = "~/MyImageHandler.ashx";
   ```
2. Embed the image using the [`Data URI scheme`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). In this case you could directly use the `<img>` HTML tag:

   ```
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= Convert.ToBase64String(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"")) %>" alt="C:\Users\User\Desktop\Section-13.png" />
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this is not my objective, as of my requirement I am getting the image in the byte[] array and I have to convert the array back to image and then bind with the image control.

Comment: Sorry that's impossible. You could do this in a Winforms or WPF application but not in a web application. The only way to achieve it is using the Data URI scheme, but bear in mind that not all browsers support it. I have updated my answer to illustrate an example of the Data URI scheme embedded into an `<img>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Create a http handler and pass handler to img src tag

```
 <img src="/imagehandler.ashx" />




 public class ImageHandler : IHttpHandler
    {
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            byte[] buffer = imageToByteArray();
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer , 0, buffer .Length);
            context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why loading the entire image in memory? What if the image if pretty large and you have lots of requests? Might run quickly out of memory with this approach. See my answer for the correct way to implement such handler.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov:Agree my approach will hurt the performance.but if the image is not available on filsytem in that case

Comment: No, what I meant is that in your ProcessRequest you shouldn't be using the `imageToByteArray();`. Once again, checkout my generic handler for the correct way to implement this. Notice that in my example the image is not inside the folder structure of the website (Possibility 1). Notice the use of `WriteFile` method which streams the image directly to the response in chunks without loading it entirely into a buffer as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Make **[Data URL Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme)**

```
data:[<MIME-type>][;charset=<encoding>][;base64],<data>
```

In Image control

```
<asp:image id="reddot" runat="server" ImageUrl="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

Commonly this method we used for image resizing and dynamic images

http://i-skool.co.uk/net/resize-and-optimise-image-class-in-c/

```
Image2.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64,"  + Convert.ToBase64String(imageToByteArray(image1))
```

Image to Byte Array

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will  also go for this Image Handler For handling this image. i used this sample code for retrieving the image in my webform with an .ashx handler

```
 Context.Session["emp"] = "anything u could pass your id or something";
 Image1.ImageUrl = "~/img.ashx";
```

i passed the id through Context.Session and called img.ashx--> my handler

Inside handler i did

```
 public class img : IHttpHandler,System.Web.SessionState.IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        Connection connect = new Connection();
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.Session["emp"].ToString() != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    string text;
                    text =retrive your data from here by using  context.Session["emp"]
                    DataTable dt1 = connect.exexc(text, connect.connectfunction());
                    if (dt1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string img = dt1.Rows[0].ItemArray[0].ToString();--> i retrived the byte array here
                        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(img);
                        context.Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
                        context.Response.BinaryWrite(imageBytes);
                    }
                 }
                catch
                {

                }
            }
         }
        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```